# Ladon control order of elements inside LadonType

Tags: python, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm using [`Ladon`](http://www.ladonize.org) to expose a webservice in Python. I've a `LadonType` as followed:

```
class Message(LadonType):
    msg_from = PORTABLE_STRING
    reply1 = PORTABLE_STRING
    reply2 = PORTABLE_STRING
    department = PORTABLE_STRING
    date = PORTABLE_STRING
```

Now when I generate WSDL, it appears something like this:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Message">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="date" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="department" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="msg-from" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="reply1" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="reply2" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

That is, order of the elements is changed in the generated WSDL from what I defined while writing the `Message` class.

Also, in the soap response, there is no way to control each individual elements of a complex structure, and they are generated arbitrarily. But since in the generated WSDL,It's `</xsd:sequence>` should not the order be maintained? My client also needs the order to be maintained.

Can I control and set a fixed order of elements inside a complex structure `LadonType` object?

Comment: I don't know the answer but I have to ask... Why does your client need the order preserved? Whatever you're using to consume the service should handle all that implicitly. Of course, when it comes to lists, order is important, but properties on an object?

Comment: I agree with you, client should not require them to be in order. But just to comply with the generated WSDL... since it's saying `sequence` shouldn't it be maintained in generated output?